# Cannot Expand FileSystem

Tags: filesystem

When I first install the Wheezy OS on a Kingston 8GB class 10 SD card, using Win32DiskImager, it works fine, but the second that I try to expand the FileSystem by bringing up the config screen (sudo raspi-config), and expand the FileSystem, i get the message that in the next boot up, it will attempt to resize the FileSystem, but when I boot up it just hangs for ever. 
I read some blogs that it says this resizing may take some time, well I even let it stay overnight (over 6 hours), but it hangs forever. 
I tried to repeat this process few times by formatting the disk with my PC (fat32), and run Win32DiskImager again, but the same thing keeps happening. 
If I don't attempt to resize the FileSystem, everything appears to be working fine, I can install programs, and have no issue at all, but the problems start when I try to resize the FS.
I would appreciate some help.

Thanks,
--Rudy

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with the terminal, you can use gparted to manually expand the partition. It's a delicate process, but it's not too difficult for anyone. I followed [this tutorial](http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions). Like they say in the tutorial, don't worry about swap space. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, but later I delete the partion in gparted, and ran raspi-config, it works. Just give a try.